# return the sum of int[

Tags: java, arrays

This is my code using loops. Assume that num is not null or empty;

```
public int[] num;

public double[] sumNum() {
    double[] sum;
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + num[i];
        }
        return sum;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: sum should not be an array

Comment: What's your problem? By Robin Li

Answer (score 1):

If you want to devise a function to sum the values of an array, consider the below:

```java
public int sumNum(int[] num) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + num[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

It doesn't make sense to return a `double` for a function like this, but you still can. I changed it to `int` since `num` is always `int` as per its declaration. I'm only making an assumption to what you really wanted.

Also consider taking `num` as argument for the function, thereby giving it local scope within the function. You could keep it global but again, I'm making an assumption of what you really want. Plus, it allows for re-using this function if you ever wanted to find the sum of something else.

You also want some initial value for `sum`: since you're summing the values in an array, I initialized `sum` to `0`. Otherwise, when you do `sum = sum + num[i]`, *what* exactly is `sum` initially? You need some starting point.